# Azure IOT hub device partitioning

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am currently working on a platform that has ~50,000 devices connected to an Azure IOT hub. We have been running into performance issues due to unbalanced partitioning of these devices. Basically, if a device is running in a given partition that contains more devices, than another partition with less devices it is less performant. We have configured the IOT hub with the maximum number of partitions (32), yet we continue to experience this issue where too many devices reside in the same partition. As I understand it, the partition assignment is based on the device Id, which in our case is a GUID, and behind the scenes there is a hashing algorithm which decides which partition a device will reside.

We have attempted to resolve the issue using an undocumented .NET Framework API EventHubPartitionKeyResolver.ResolveToPartition (removed in .NET Core) which essentially runs the hashing algorithm on the input, device Id, and returns the partition it would reside in. With this we can iterate on generating a new devices Id, until it falls into a partition we know is less crowded.
This kind of works but is less than optimal.

I am wondering if anyone else has run into this issue of unbalanced IOT hub partitions, and if so how have you dealt with it.

Answer (score 0):

> One way is we can use custom [allocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/concepts-custom-allocation) policies to define your own allocation policies when the built-in policies provided by the Device Provisioning Service (DPS) don't meet the requirements of  scenario. Custom allocation policies give you more control over how devices are assigned to your IoT hubs. By using custom allocation policies, you can define your own allocation policies when the built-in policies provided by the Device Provisioning Service (DPS) don't meet the requirements of  scenario.

- For more details refer to  custom allocation policies enable provisioning to multiple [IoT hubs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-configuration-best-practices.md) with the Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning [Service](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-dps/concepts-custom-allocation.md).

[image]

Another method is to modify device IDs to control partition assignment.
manually assign devices to specific partitions by creating multiple IoT hubs and directing devices to different hubs.a